# How to verify multiple addresses using EasyPost

Tags: reactjs, easypost

Is there any possibility to verify multiple addresses using EasyPost "verify address" API? Batch object doesn't work as expected and "verify address" API accepts single address. To be more precise, I want to send one request with multiple addresses to verify and not many requests for many addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently an option using the EasyPost API. You're welcome to send a message to support@easypost.com to request that feature.

Comment: so the only option right now is to send multiple requests? e.g. 100 requests for 100 addresses?

Comment: Correct. Most of the time people are verifying addresses during Shipment creation.